What does " It was dark as night out, still storming." mean?
I found the following sentences while reading the book "Let's Get Invisible" by R.L Stine. The book describes a birthday party on a rainy day. Near the end of the party the main character says:

I guess it was about five o’clock. It looked much later. It was dark as
night out, still storming.

I'm wondering what does " It was dark as night out, still storming." mean. Does that mean the outside was dark similar to nighttime and it was still storming? If that is the case, I think the punctuation should indicate a pause after "night" and maybe use "still storming" in the next sentence.

The first part means it was very dark.  It was the same darkness as nighttime. "Out" means "outside".
The second part tells you that the weather was a storm.
When there is a storm, the clouds make the sky dark.

I wonder if the confusion is with out. I'm reading it not as part of the simile (It was dark as a night out), but a location marker: (Outside, it was dark as night).

Thanks. At first it was hard for me to comprehend the sentence but as I changed the way I read, helped me to clear the confusion. I think listening to audiobooks would be helpful for such situations.

Merriam-Webster in fact gives outside as the very first definition of out, and It was raining out as an example sentence.

These are all idiomatic ways of talking about the experience of being outdoors or the current conditions outdoors:

It was hot as hell out and very humid.
You should wear a heavier coat. It's freezing out.
It's really nice out. There's not a cloud in the sky.
No, you can't go out and play. It's  dark out.
Bring your umbrella. It's still raining out.

But "out" is not a shortened form of "outdoors" and the word "out", when it refers to conditions outdoors, cannot appear at the head of a clause or phrase:

Out it was hot as hell and very humid.ungrammatical
It was dark, out still storming. ungrammatical

